# Knockout 3.1: Select2 not working properly with valueAllowUnset

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2, knockout-3.0

I noticed that when I use `valueAllowUnset: true` with the Select2 plugin, the default value is not visible in the select box. However, when I click on the select, the correct value is highlighted.

http://jsfiddle.net/LgXcb/

Try removing '`, select2: {}`' from the above fiddle to see how it should work.

Any ideas on what's causing this issue? Does it have to do with the select2 custom binding function I'm using for Knockout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I always end up finding a solution right after setting up a bounty, even if I wait months before starting that bounty.

The problem was with the code inside the `update` function of my custom binding. After the observable value of the select changes, I also need to manually update select2, like so:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
  var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().value || allBindingsAccessor().selectedOptions);
  if (value) $(element).select2('val', value);
}
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/LgXcb/5/

Comment: Beat me to it, I was just starting to look at if the `select2` plugin would listen to the underlying `select` element for changes.  Would be a nice feature for them to add in the future to it.

Comment: So the `select2` github has an snippet of code for ko integration, go figure!

Comment: Yep, I tried using their ko code as well, didn't work. Thanks for helping me out on this!

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, your `setTimeout` call is causing issues.  Why? I'm not sure yet, but if you remove that and make a direct call to `getSemesters()` at the end of the function, it will select the initial value selected.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgXcb/4/)

I will keep looking at it and update you if I find the exact cause of this.

---

### Update

It is amazing what you can find when you look at the [github](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration) for the `select2` plugin.

Comment: I'm using `setTimeout` to simulate the ajax call in my original code which provides the options for the select. The `selectedSemester` observable is the default value and it loads before the ajax response. `valueAllowUnset: true` prevents the observable from being overwritten until I populate the list. The problem is with select2, which fails to update its label, even though when opened, the correct value is selected.